# jQuery Validation Engine - Required Field using regular expression

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery Validation Engine in asp.net form. How do I validate a field (required) **using a regular expression**?

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#aspnetForm").validationEngine('attach', {
        'custom_error_messages': {
            // Custom Error Messages for Validation Types
            '.reqSomeField': {
                'required': {
                    'message': "Please enter Some Field."
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried thus far?

But here's something that might help you get started. It's from the [docucmentation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).

custom[regex_name]
  Validates the element’s value to a predefined list of regular expressions.

So first you'd need to create your custom regex in the jquery-validation-engine.js file, then call it in the form field. The syntax, in the form field, would be something like this:

```
<input value="someone@nowhere.com" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
```

Have you tried simply adding this class to the form fields?

```
<input value="" class="validate[required]" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
```

That doesn't do any validation other than force the user to put SOMETHING in the field. However, they could enter $$$ into the field, and the form would see that as valid. If you're doing inline validation, and using this plugin in particular, you might want to use the existing validation options for email addresses, something that has letters and numbers but no punctuation, a numbers-only field, et cetera. The pre-existing options are all listed in the documentation.

Comment: Yes. I do know that i need to modify the jquery-validation-engine.js file. I am using custom validation (please see my original post for more details, I added just now). And I am not what is the regular expression for 'Required Field'. So, two questions 1. If I use custom validation, regular expression part is not working. 2. As I said not sure what is the regular expression for 'Required Field'

Comment: So you just want an error message to pop up telling people "this field is required"? Nothing about what type of content needs to go into the field? If you just want them to put something - anything - into the field, you can use validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber]] - but with this plugin, there are already so many other options. You can force them to type in only numbers. Or only letters. Or something that's in the format of an email address. Or a certain number of numbers (ie, they must enter between 3 and 10 numbers into the field.)

Comment: Also: it looks like you're trying to put some global validation in the instantiation code. As I understand and have used the plugin, you have to attach the validation classes to the individual form fields to be validated, not to the overall document instantiation.